# Vassiliev invariant calculation

Tags: knot-theory, knot-invariants

I have this question but I have no idea how to begin. Could someone give a solution for K_1?

[image: Question]

Comment: What do you know? Where did you get stuck? Did you read the chapter before these exercises and understand it (or understood most of it)?

Answer (score 0):

*(I am hesitant answering this question, especially since the asker seems to have disappeared, but I need some practice calculating with finite-type invariants anyway.)*

The definition of $v_2$ is specifying its value using *chord diagram*.  The chords specify which points are the double points for the map $S^1\to S^3$.  For $K_1$, the following singular knots are useful:

[image: chord diagram as knot]

Expanding the first diagram gives

[image: Expansion of knot]

where the second term in the first expansion is $0$ since its two expansions are unknots and cancel out.  Thus, $v_2$ of the right-handed trefoil is $a+b$.